# Empty response after sending request to couchDB

Tags: json, couchdb, httprequest

I've got problem with CouchDB request. Record from view looks like:

```
{
"total_rows":79293,
"offset":0,
"rows":[
{"id":"401417608421000",
"key":["2015-08-03T12:07:01+0000"],
"value":0}]
}
```

request looks like:

```
http:/ip:port/testDB/_design/reports/_view/experiments?key=["2015-08-03T12:07:01+0000"]
```

it returns

```
{
"total_rows":79382,
"offset":0,
"rows":[ ]
}
```

I read https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options
and change url to

```
http:/ip:port/testDB/_design/reports/_view/experiments?key=%5B%222015-08-03T12:0‌​7:01+0000%22%5D
```

but it didn't helped.

Directly I want to send request with startDate and endDate.

Comment: Have you tried to look by id just to make sure that http access works as expected? Dates are often tricky and maybe it is being converted to a different timezone.

Comment: @R4J unfortunately, It have to be by date.. For your information, requests with id or name works fine.

Comment: @JanKowalski could you show your view code as well?

Comment: @JanKowalski also, after reading the Querying Options section you linked, I noticed they're using the query parameter "keys" instead of "key".

Answer (score 0):

It's the plus sign that is making the query fail. If you encode the url you should at least try to encode the entire parameter, this works for me:

```
?key=%5B"2015-08-03T12%3A07%3A01%2B0000"%5D
```

And after a bit of testing I found the plus sign to be the problem, so a prettier key-parameter looks like this and works for me:

```
?key=["2015-08-03T12:07:01%2B0000"]
```